# How to shrink one area if another grows with CSS?

Tags: css, html

I need to achieve one effect using html and CSS:

```
+-------------------+-----------------+ 
|some text bla bla  |other text here  |
+-------------------+-----------------+

+--------------+----------------------+
| some text b..|bigger other text here|
+--------------+----------------------+
```

The size of the main container is fixed. And I need that second area always grows, and first shrinks if text is overflow.

Is it possible with CSS?

Comment: So you want the second area to cover the text of the first area if the first area's text doesn't fit in a single line?

Comment: Yes. First are width is (mainArea - secondArea).

Comment: Down vote without explanations. If I am asking something stupid please explain.

Answer (score 2):

I think it is impossible with css, even with css3

It would work with javascript and explicitly defined width

Comment: we make this by using the different division like div1(div2,div3) and set font size and width different/ described above? isn't it ?

Answer (score 1):

The best solution I can think off (with only CSS), is using `position:absolute;` on the div/span/p/whatever that you have on the right, so it will stay on top of the element on the left. Here's a live example: http://jsfiddle.net/Cthulhu/6DrQX/

However, this is not exactly a nice solution, so I would also use javascript like stefan bachert proposed.